# Canopy 1.6.2 installation on OSX 10.9.5 - crashes -> won't start up

Tags: python, macos, enthought, canopy

Just upgraded to 1.6.2 by copying the canopy executable into Applications, and after a couple of screens (including "factory reset"), the GUI now crashes on startup every time.

The Canopy GUI splash screen error message only comes up for < 1 second:

Startup failure ImportError: No module named ipykernel

It's not possible to check the box for recovery manager - where can I find this on my system?

That's fine - I only need the command line - but now I am getting failures like this:

```
from scipy import stats
ImportError: cannot import name stats
```

I have just restarted the machine but the scipy.stats error is the same.

Is it possible to rollback?

Incomplete installation?

This procedure does not fix it: https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469700-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, the problem here was multiple references to other python installations and site-packages in `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`. Clearing these environment variables of references to other python environments allowed Canopy to start.

Answer (score 0):

> This procedure does not fix it

Did you delete all the directories specified in that procedure and then try unsuccessfully to restart? If so, then please try one more time (delete all the directories, then try to restart), than zip your `~/.canopy` directory and send it (with a reference to this question) to support@enthought.com